# ngOnit starts executing before app.component.ts async function is finished - only on hard refresh in web

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, capacitor

The execution of this:

```
async initialize() {
        try {
          // Check connections consistency
          await this.sqliteService.checkConnectionConsistency().then(async r => {
            console.log(templateAppDataSource.isInitialized)
            if (!templateAppDataSource.isInitialized) {
              await templateAppDataSource.initialize().then(async _ => {
                for (const dataSource of [templateAppDataSource]) {
                  const database = String(dataSource.options.database);
                  if (!dataSource.isInitialized) {
                    // initialize the DataSource
                    await dataSource.initialize();
                    console.log(`*** dataSource has been initialized ***`)
                    // run the migrations
                    await dataSource.runMigrations();
    
                    console.log(`*** dataSource runMigration has been run succesfully ***`)
                    // load the data for this datasource
                    console.log(`*** datasource and database has has been initialized ***`)
                    // }
                    if (this.sqliteService.getPlatform() === 'web') {
                      // save the databases from memory to store
                      await this.sqliteService.getSqliteConnection().saveToStore(database);
                      console.log(`*** inORMService saveToStore ***`)
                    }
                  }
                  console.log(`DataSource: ${database} initialized`);
                }
    
    
                this.isOrmService = true;
              })
    
    
            } else {
              console.log("Connection Already Extrablsihed ")
            }
          });
    
          // Loop through your DataSources
    
    
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
        }
      }
```

Runs fine when the app is first loaded, however on refreshing the page the `initialize()` method jumps out mid way trough on first `await` and `ngOnit` on other page gets triggered.

`ngOnit` is fetching some data and db is not initialised yet as the `async` function is not yet finished initialising it?

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because you are mixing await with .then. Pick one.

Comment: what you whant? initialize() start before onInit()?

Comment: @E.Maggini doesn't make a difference the code jumps out straight to ngOnit on the first await this.sqliteService.checkConnectionConsistency()

Comment: Can you provide your code without then (or without await)? Also, why not using a service for this kind of work?

Answer (score 0):

It's a wild guess based on your code and context, but you can try using a service to initialize the DB and know when it's ready. It could be something like this:

`src/app/services/database-init.service.ts`

```js
// omitting imports for clarity

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class DatabaseInitService {
  private readonly _dbIsReady$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);
  readonly dbIsReady$ = this._dbIsReady$.asObservable();

  // omitting DI for clarity

  async initAsync() {
    // the process of initialization

    this._dbIsReady$.next(true);
  }
}
```

`src/app/app.component.ts`

```js
// imports, code...

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(/* some imports*/, private dbInitService: DatabaseInitService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    await this.dbInitService.initAsync();
  }
}
```

And now you can do something like this:

```js
// imports, code...

export class MyComp implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();
 
  // you can use the reactive approach like this:
  message$ = this.dbInitService.dbIsReady.pipe(
    filter(Boolean), // this will ensure that you have a true value here before continuing
    map(() => 'Hello there!'),
    takeUntil(this.destroy$)
  );
  
  messageBis!: string;

  private _subscription!: Subscription;

  constructor(private dbInitService: DatabaseInitService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // or you can use a subscribe
    this._subscription = this.dbInitService.dbIsReady$.subscribe((value) => {
      if (!value) return;

      this.messageBis = 'General Kenobi';
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();

    // Note that you don't need this Subject and these lines if you choose the "subscribe" way.
    this._destroy$.next();
    this._destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

This way is not very "dev friendly", as you have to make sure that the DB is ready before doing anything else. It's also very "fault proof", because we can imagine a function that will periodically make sure that the DB is still OK and if it's not, it will update the `dbIsReady$` observable. With that way, you can notify the user that something went wrong and press reload maybe.

Note that you could also "block" the UI with a spinner for example until the DB is ready. This will make sure that when the user navigates through the app, the DB is correctly initialized. There's plenty of ways to do this. Use Google ;)